# Error while powering on: VMware Player cannot connect to the virtual machine

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, vmware

**Im using Windows8, the problem is while connecting to Ubuntu though VMware I receives an error that I do not have a rights. It is not my first time I use it. Don't know what gone wrong.
The error I have got :** 
Error while powering on: VMware Player cannot connect to the virtual machine. Make sure you have rights to run the program, access all directories the program uses, and access all directories for temporary files.

The VMware Authorization Service is not running.

Comment: I found in manuals the resolution:  To start the VMware Authorization service or to check whether it's running:
Login to the Windows operating system as the Administrator.
Click Start and then type Run. If you are unable to find the Run option, refer to Microsoft article What happened to the Run command?
Type services.msc and click OK.
Scroll down the list and locate that the VMware Authorization service.
Click Start the service, unless the service is already showing a status of Started.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

This worked for me:

1. Open Task Manager Kill all the VMware Processes
2. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> --> Type (Services.msc)
3. Go to VMware Authorization service and Click START
4. Start VMware and Power ON your Virtual Machine

Comment: This worked great for me. Running as admin did not. Amazing how this $#^* happened to my build server when I needed to get a build out asap.

Comment: I didn't have that service running. So after closing vmware, I just stopped and restarted all the services of vmware (#4) and it worked also.

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar problem. For me this worked:

In command prompt (cmd) opened as administrator type services.msc and click OK.
Then scroll down the list and locate that the VMware Authorization service and start the service.

Also I followed this [steps](http://www.pc-freak.net/blog/windows-vmware-start-stop-command-line-bat-script/) to kill all processes before.

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me was running VMware as an administrator.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I hate this but, have you tried to reboot your PC ? In my case, I have tried : restart services ; run in admin ; delete lock folder ; delete process of VMWare ; start another VM (if it would fix the boot)

But none of that worked, except... restarting the pc

Comment: This was the correct answer for me, too. I did everything, but the VM only started working without any problems after restarting the PC

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the following steps, and I am sure it will help

Close the VMware. Open the Task manager, then go to Services.

Click on Open Services which you will find right at the bottom of the screen. A new window will open. 
Now scroll down and go to VMware Workstation Server.
Right Click on it and go to properties. You will see a drop down list next to Startup Type. 
Click on it and select Automatic (Delayed Start), then apply the changes. 
Now again right click on VMware Workstation Server and click on Start, you will immediately see a popup which will show you that the remote server is starting up.
Once this is done, go to VMware workstation and start it.

Now you will be able to start your virtual machine .

Hope this helps, all the best.

Answer (score 0):

I get this issue in VMWare Workstation on Win 10. It usually happens after VMWare hangs for a guest that is located on an external USB hard drive. Restarting the pc works but going to Task Manger and killing the 'VMWare Workstation VMX' (may be named something slightly differently) also works for me and is obviously preferable to a restart.